# Get the official music video from YouTube API

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

Similar question: [How to detect official artist channel using youtube api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55928904/how-to-detect-official-artist-channel-using-youtube-api)

The problem at hand is to find the official music video using the YouTube API.

To be more specific:

1. Not only put a **filter** to get only Music video as shown here: [Youtube API - search only music videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981358/youtube-api-search-only-music-videos)
2. The actual link in YouTube is [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ/videos)
3. I can always **go through some 5 results and choose** based on views, but my search space is already large and I want to **minimize it one query** per song.
4. A major problem with point 1 and 3 combined is that there is a chance of a **fan-made cover to have more views**.

A working alternative I tried was like this: `youtube_search(song_name + " VEVO")`, This works of course only for big artists as you may have guessed.

To actually do it, I figured if YouTube API only searched in the link in point 2 then the work is done.

Is that possible or is there a better way?

Comment: How do you characterize the video as official?

Comment: A video is official if it's uploaded by the artist, say this is official for Despacito: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJQP7kiw5Fk , this is not: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whwe0KD_rGw

Comment: How do you know if an account is an artist's account? Anyone can claim to be an artist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121635/youtube-api-official-content-only?rq=1

Comment: Any video in point 2, i.e. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ/videos is official. Can we reduce the API's search space to that is part of the question

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python and  cmd/ctrl f "search"

Comment: @GaneshK did you could get the videos from the https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ/videos ? and/or  are you still looking for a answer to your question?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if the API permits this now, but I just got around by looking for other metadata of the video to determine if it was official. If you did find a way please do post it, else I can post the metadata I considered which gave me decent results

Comment: @GaneshKathiresan , I know this is pretty old at this point, but curious what meta data you ended up using. I'd ideally like to identify if a video's channel is an 'Official Artist Channel' from the api results, been looking and can't find a good way to do it

Comment: Hi @Garrett, most of my videos were by popular artist so were published by vevo. You should be able to extrapolate that idea if you are looking for a particular kind of artist. Some other info were likes, views, number of comments. Of course some cover artist might have more but is pretty rare.

Comment: [@GarrettSimpson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380990/garrett-simpson) 
Please let me know if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74893025) on a very similar StackOverflow question solves your problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison, thanks for finding and linking this. I marked this question as a duplicate of yours, and linked it in the question,